# React URLs without hash (#) redirect to include the hash or loop despite front controller rule in .htaccess

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

My React web page works correctly with the next link in my HostGator domain

`my-web-page/#/admin`

but in case that I try to type the URL manually to

`my-web-page/admin`

it begins to reload in a loop until I go back to the correct page. Is there a way to correct this fact with an `.htaccess`, actually I have this content

```bash
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

but still doesn't work

instead to redirect to `my-web-page/#/admin` I tried to type `my-web-page/admid` and get the correct URL.

Comment: Do you have anything else in your .htaccess file apart from the directives as posted? Is “my-web-page” supposed to your domain name / hostname or part of the URL-path?

Comment: originally it had the next content

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
but then i tried to change it

Answer (score 0):

> it begins to reload in a loop

This sounds like an issue with the routing in your React app?

However, to redirect requests for `example.com/anything` (single path segment) to `example.com/#/anything` you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/anything" to "/#/anything"
RewriteRule ^([\w-]*)$ /#/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Where "anything" is a single path segment consisting of any combination of characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) or `-` (hyphen).

Note that this also includes the root itself, ie. `example.com/` is redirected to `example.com/#/`. If that is not required then change the quantifier in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `*` (0 or more) to `+` (1 or more).

The `NE` flag is necessary to prevent the `#` being URL-encoded in the redirect response (`Location` header).

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once fully tested.

Note that your existing/original mod_rewrite directive that routes requests to `index.html` (the "front controller") is not used/required when the URL is of the form `example.com/#/something`.